# T-SQL Generate Random/Sample Data from RegEx

Tags: t-sql

I have to generate some random data, but from Regular Expression given.

For example I have these rules:

```
 1) IsRegEx('^(((([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9])?)?:)?[0-5])?[0-9]$', #COMMENT#)
 2) IsRegEx('^[0-9]+:([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$',#COMMENT#)
 3) IsRegEx( '^[0-9]+$' , #COMMENT#)
```

and many others... I have to generate text `#Comment#` which will pass the rule. It is not necessary to there are many variations, one is enough.

Have anyone do something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this in Sql Server - thru CLR stored procedure or CLR user defined function, if your Sql Server version allows this. Else - there is no any acceptable way.

Comment: There is no problem to do this with stored procedure. I am asking about idea or easy way to do this. I can write a some checks, for example if I have "[0-9]+" to contact to my string random number from 0 to 9, but there are so many variants, that it will consume too much time doing it in this way.

Comment: As I said - there is no easy, acceptable and fast way to do it in native T-SQL

Comment: @Joro a CLR stored procedure is not the same as a t-sql stored procedure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

Comment: @Ben, thank you. Yes, there are. It seems to me too complicate but I will try this. Thanks, again, all of you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with T-SQL. T-SQL doesn't even support regular expressions. If you have Visual Studio Premium you can create a database project and use a regular expression data generator to create the test data you want. Check "[Generating Test Data for Databases using Data Generators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193262.aspx)".

If you don't have VS Premium you can create your own generator as a [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255336.aspx)